# Extracting year from a date timestamp in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to convert a column in a database into a timestamp format, then I want to see the number of counts for each year.

I have:

```
SELECT
    (column_name::date), count(*)
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM column_name)
FROM table
GROUP BY column_name;
```

'I get an error message that says no function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.'

Is extract the wrong function?

Comment: what type is `column_name` ?

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Answer (score 8):

You probably want something like this if `column_name` is timestamp

search for **[EXTRACT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-datetime.html)** documentation

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM column_name), count(*)        
FROM table
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM column_name);
```

if `column_name` is string you need **[to_timestamp()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html)** function

Comment: interesting enough this returns a double precision... most of the time you'll want `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM column_name)::int`